# querying a json in angular

Tags: json, angular

I have a Json with 2 differents objects: readers and books, something like this:

```
{
"users": [{
        "id": 1,
        "username": "peterB",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "MaryC"
    }
],

"books": [{
        "id": 10,
        "user": 1,
        "title": "test1"
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "user": 1,
        "title": "test2"
    }
]
}
```

In my html I want to display each books with the username related to it. using ngFor="let book of books"> {{book.title}} owned by {{book.username}} ....

I can't find a way to get this in my component, I am only getting the list of books

```
 books: any;
getBooks() {
this.http.get("assets/data.json")
.subscribe((success) => {
  this.books = success.json().books;});}
```

Does anyone has any ideas how to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could map through the books and search every user related to it:

```js
const data = {
  users: [
    {
      id: 1,
      username: "peterB"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      username: "MaryC",
      real_name: "Conan O'Brien",
      verified: true
    }
  ],
  books: [
    {
      id: 10,
      user: 1,
      title: "test1"
    },
    {
      id: 33,
      user: 1,
      title: "test2"
    }
  ]
};

const booksWithUsers = data.books.map(book => ({
  ...book,
  user: data.users.find(({ id }) => id === book.user)
}));

console.log(booksWithUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this nesting the user object in the book object...

Like this

```
{
"books": [{
        "id": 10,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "peterB"
         },
        "title": "test1"
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "MaryC",
            "real_name": "Conan O'Brien",
            "verified": true
        },
        "title": "test2"
    }
]
}
```